# Are there any fake JSON APIs for store/ecommerce?

Tags: json, mocking

Is there any site where I can get fake JSON which have an array of object related to the store that includes the image, price, name so that I can improve my skill related to JSON Rest APIs with GET and POST?

Please suggest me site other than a fake JSON placeholder.

Comment: Before this gets shut down, I personally use https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Comment: i also used jsonplaceholder.com for practise but for sorting data practice it doesnt provide me any amount so i cant stick in it

Comment: you can download their source and create your own mock API

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest trying Beeceptor, that helps to build mock API in no time. Easy to use for most businesses or developers who are struggling with API.

https://beeceptor.com/mock-server/fake-store-api

Answer (score 0):

I used [JSON BLOB](https://jsonblob.com/) to store JSON and creating links like APIs to teach my students.

Follow the steps to create JSON and get it over URL:

1. Create JSON into the editor
2. Click on the `save` button in the header.
3. You will get a link something like, **https://jsonblob.com/e29c9fd2-13be-11e9-aac5-659aad2453a7**
4. In the link replace https://jsonblob.com/ to https://jsonblob.com/api, in my case the new link will be https://jsonblob.com/api/e29c9fd2-13be-11e9-aac5-659aad2453a7
5. That's it! It will work like an API.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to please once try [fake-store-api](https://fakestoreapi.com/) .I have personally used this in my e-commerce projects.